# Copy duplicate rows in Excel based on a column condition

Tags: vba, excel

When adding a new row in a worksheet in Excel I'm looking to ensure that if columns D and E exist together in column D and E of another existing row, column F from that existing row is copied into column F in the new row.

```
  A    B    C    D    E    F
  A    B    C    D    E    F
  A    B    C    D    E    F
 NEW  NEW  NEW  NEW  NEW  NEW
```

Can this be done using the IF function or is it easier to produce in VBA?

Comment: So the new **F** sill be linked back to the old **E** ?

Comment: Apologies - I've edited. Existing F should be linked to the new F

Comment: [Have you tried either approach?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) If so, what worked, what didn't work? I'd say the easiest route would be to use an `IF` formula in column `F` to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this small macro:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim N As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim i As Long
    d = Cells(N, "D").Value
    e = Cells(N, "E").Value

    For i = N - 1 To 1 Step -1
        dt = Cells(i, "D").Value
        et = Cells(i, "E").Value
        If d = dt And e = et Then
            MsgBox "match found"
            Cells(N, "F").Value = Cells(i, "F").Value
        Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i
    MsgBox "no match found"
End Sub
```

So first fill in both cells **E** and **D** in the new row and then run the macro.

Comment: Many thanks for pointing me in the right direction with this - it works up until the point where it displays the message box. Unfortunately it wasn't copying the value from F into the new F row though. Will play around with it and see if I can make it work on my spreadsheet!

Comment: Works a charm, actually, thankyou! How would I modify the `For i` into a `For Each` statement?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a formula to create a helper column that can find the appropriate values.

The formula has to be defined as an array formula, as we need to return an array from the matches of the first check, so we can have an array ready for the second test.

First, we build an array from the first test, and then only give the values in the second column, that correspond to matches in the first column: `IF($E$1:$E$10=E1,$D$1:$D$10)`

then from that array, we look for our second value, and get the position: `MATCH(D1,TheArray,0)`

From that values, we then look in column F for the matching value: `INDEX($F$1:$F$10,ThePosition)`

Putting that all into one formula gives

```
=INDEX($F$1:$F$10,MATCH(D1,IF($E$1:$E$10=E1,$D$1:$D$10),0))
```

Don't press enter just yet - remember we have to let excel know it's an array formula? To do this, instead of just pressing enter, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> - if you've done this right, you should be rewarded with `{}` around the formula:

```
{=INDEX($F$1:$F$10,MATCH(D1,IF($E$1:$E$10=E1,$D$1:$D$10),0))}
```

You can then either hide column F, or copy values from the helper column over column F in your data.